# Why does venlafaxine have lower incidence of sexual dysfunctions at higher doses?

Tags: sexuality, depression, psychopharmacology, serotonin, neuro-transmitters

Venlafaxine at low dosages strongly inhibits serotonin, at moderate dosages also norepinephrine and only high dosages it also inhibits dopamine.

The ratio is the following.

- serotonin : norepinephrine : dopamine
- 1 : 30 : 93

According to the [FDA data](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/label/2009/020151s054lbl.pdf) these are the percentages for side effects.

- Libido decreased
- Placebo 75mg **225mg** 375mg
- 1.1% 2.2% **1.1%** 5.7%

Here are the results for other sexual dysfunctions.

- Abnormal ejaculation/orgasm
- Placebo 75mg **225mg** 375mg
- 0.0% 4.5% **2.2%** 12.5%

and

- Impotence
- Placebo 75mg **225mg** 375mg
- 0.0% 5.8% **2.1%** 3.6%

**How would you explain the sudden drop of sexual dysfunctions at 225mg?**

Other questions to consider:

- Would a lower dose (37.5mg or 25mg) have sexual side effects (SSE) similar to placebo?
- What dose has the lowest rate of SSE?
- What is the lowest effective dose with reasonably low SSE?
- How would adding of NDRI (bupropione) influence SSE given an increased dosage of venlafaxine? (i.e. Could one afford higher doses
  of venlafaxine with few SSE provided bupropion is taken
  concomittantly?)

Comment: Seeing as you asked a similar question a while ago at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/21298/induced-sexual-dysfunctions-antipsychotics-vs-antidepressants are you in any position to write an answer to that question or is this one an offshoot after further research?

Comment: The difference between  2.2% and 1.1% may not be statistically significant.